# How to access an PHP object when the key begins with a Number

Tags: php, arrays

maybe a simple question but i don't get it.
How can i access an PHP object when the key begins with a Number?

```
$myArray->24h_sel

$myArray["24h_sel"] // did not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use braces and quotes: `$myArray->{'24h_sel'};`.